# Tablet Layouts definition

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm checking this article: [Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and in the **Range of screens supported** section it says:

> A set of four generalized sizes: small, normal, large, and xlarge
>
> **Note**: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), these size groups are deprecated in favor of a new technique for managing screen sizes based on the available screen width. If you're developing for Android 3.2 and greater, see Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2 for more information.

The "developing for Android 3.2 and greater" sentence refers to the **target** SDK version or the **min** SDK version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13)

So this means Android version > 3.2.

So the minimum is 3.2.

So it's the min SDK version.